# How can I solve "laravel/horizon v1.1.0 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system"?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.5, laravel-horizon

When I run `composer install` on command promp, there exist error like this :

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/horizon v1.1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/horizon[v1.1.0].
    - laravel/horizon v1.1.0 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp-7.1\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Run composer with the `--ignore-platform-reqs` option and specify `pcntl` and `posix`

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: There exist error like this : `Invalid argument ext-pcntl ext-posix. Use "composer require ext-pcntl ext-posix" instead to add packages to your composer.json.`

Comment: Try it with only the option: `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: I just had the same issue - for some reason unknown to me, my php got _unlinked_ (??) somehow. I found out when running `php --ini` to locate the loaded config that I wanted to check, and it said no config is loaded, none. At the end, all I needed was to relink PHP by `brew link php71 --force` and dependencies installed without a problem.

Comment: Thanks, composer install --ignore-platform-reqs worked for me!

Comment: See my answer if you don't always want to add `--ignore-platform-reqs` to every composer command https://stackoverflow.com/a/52778992/2623477

Comment: This isn't fixing the problem, it's just ignoring the error. You still need the process-control extension enabled for horizon to work as it should. You should be upgrading your php installation

Comment: Thanks, composer install --ignore-platform-reqs worked for me as well.

Comment: I don't think this is a solution. If you supress the message, then when you get around to running horizon (which we can assume you will because its in your composer.json) then you'll get an error stating that the extension is missing.

Comment: How is this the answer?

Answer (score 106):

As per the accepted answer, but you can add this to your composer.json so that you don't have to run `--ignore-platform-reqs` all the time

```
"config": {
  "platform": {
    "ext-pcntl": "8.0",
    "ext-posix": "8.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for this. Thank you!

Comment: added this but it didn't fix mine. I'm running PHP 7.3 on MAMP (on a mac)

Comment: Perfect for me, this solution worked in a window 10 PHP 7.4.15

Comment: Perfect: Worked with windows 10, PHP 8.0.3

Answer (score 27):

install horizon this way :

```
composer require laravel/horizon --ignore-platform-reqs
```

then run

```
php artisan horizon:install
```

Answer (score 17):

`pcntl` extension is **not supported on Windows**. (based on your XAMPP information)

Please see these github issues on [laravel/horizon](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/) page [#131](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/131), [#78](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/78).

I suggest you use [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/homestead) on your Windows system, It is easy to setup and will save you from many of the similar problems in future.

Comment: ...and this is the better answer: how do you expect that library to work if you cannot install one of the required PHP extensions?

Comment: @NicoHaase `--ignore-platform-reqs`... keyword being `platform`. It runs on windows without those dependencies throwing a wench in the installation process. https://okaufmann.ch/development/laravel-horizon-ext-pcntl-and-windows/

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But there must be any reason that the library requires these extensions - if they are required for the library to work properly and you ignore this requirement, they won't work properly

Comment: You're missing the point, they are required on Linux, not Windows. It works fine on Windows without the those extensions.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using docker based on a Unix image you can add it with the [docker utility](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/php/#how-to-install-more-php-extensions):

```
docker-php-ext-install pcntl
```

You can then confirm that this extension is installed and enabled inside of your container:

```
?> php -i | grep pcntl
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pcntl.ini,
pcntl
pcntl support => enabled
```

Answer (score 5):

Just run the following:

`composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Note: pcntl is not supported on Windows

Answer (score 5):

add this line

`RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl`
before

`RUN composer install`

Answer (score 5):

This works for me

```
composer require laravel/horizon --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to simply ignore the dependency is wrong. That isn't going to give you a working version of Horizon or whatever package you may be hoping to install. The dependencies must be installed.

Examples of how to install:

**APK**

```
sudo add php8-pcntl php8-pcntl
```

**Yum**

```
sudo yum install -y php-pcntl php-posix
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Windows** and get that issue - you should just ignore it since Horizon works fine without the extension and doesn't require it on Windows.

So basically you must use the next

```
composer require laravel/horizon --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Good luck!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it explains why you can ignore the platform requirements on windows and that the package still works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the package while ignoring the platform requirements.

```
composer require laravel/horizon --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Then run

```
php artisan horizon:install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on windows 10 without homestead you can enable the linux subsystem and run horizon through that.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10

Then install the requirements

```
sudo apt install php7.2-fpm php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-soap php7.2-gd php7.2-xml php7.2-cli php7.2-zip php7.2-mysql
```

This also can run laravel envoy too which doesn't work on windows.

It's a nice lightweight solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$composer install --ignore-platform-reqs ext-pcntl
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem and `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` works for me

Thanks

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs   

composer require laravel/horizon --ignore-platform-reqs

php artisan horizon:install
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [answer].

Answer (score -1):

I have installed PHP 7.2 instead of 7.1 and everything works fine now. It appears that pcntl was not present in 7.1 but it's installed with php 7.2.