# Laravel Horizon throws error : Call to undefined function Laravel\Horizon\Console\pcntl_async_signals()

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-5.7, laravel-horizon

i have succesfully installed and setup laravel-horizon as per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/horizon)

when i running this command `php artisan horizon`

it throws below error :

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to
>   undefined function Laravel\Horizon\Console\pcntl_async_signals()

[image]

When i open http://127.0.0.1:8000/horizon/dashboard , horizon dashboard status always **inactive**

[image]

Im using XAMPP , PHP Version 7.3.0 , Laravel version 5.7

I have followed this link : https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/154#issuecomment-366712260

`composer require ext-pcntl ext-posix`

here is composer :

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-pcntl": "^7.2",
        "ext-posix": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/horizon": "^2.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    },
```

I have search so many questions , but no luck , 
also tried `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` but still not working .

anyone please help me to run Laravel Horizon in my local system

Comment: Can you verify that `pcntl` extension is installed and enabled? Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: im running on Mac OS 10.13.6

Comment: Have you published `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Horizon\HorizonServiceProvider"` ?

Comment: @HirenGohel , yes i have done

Comment: @SaurabhMistry: Ok, Seems like you don't have the `pcntl` extension installed as error show i think, can you try to install it?

Comment: @HirenGohel , i have tried to install it using `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs ext-pcntl ext-posix
`  but it is not working

Comment: @HirenGohel , i have followed this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577465/how-can-i-solve-laravel-horizon-v1-1-0-requires-ext-pcntl-the-requested-ph

Comment: @SaurabhMistry can you run `php -i | grep pcntl` and verify that `pcntl` and `pcntl support => enabled` is printed out?

Comment: @LukaPeharda , i have just tried `php -i | grep pcntl` nothing got printed , can you tell me what should i do ?

Comment: @SaurabhMistry that means that you didn't install and enable `pcntl`. Try and find some tutorial with instructions on how to install `pcntl` on XAMPP (as it seems that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577465/how-can-i-solve-laravel-horizon-v1-1-0-requires-ext-pcntl-the-requested-ph didn't work for you)

Comment: @LukaPeharda , i have successfully installed `composer require ext-pcntl ext-posix` , but still got same error

Answer (score 2):

After searching 2 hours finally i resolved error :

As Im using XAMPP , i have to set `PATH` in `bash_profile` file to use XAMPP's php 7.3.0

so I added this in

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile

export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP
export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

then reload bash_profile using ,

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

then i Check php version by

```
php -v
```

it will display below :

> PHP 7.3.0 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2018 01:01:47) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.3.0-dev, Copyright (c)
>   1998-2018 Zend Technologies

then i check `php -i | grep pcntl`

it will display :

> pcntl support => enabled

so i try to run `php artisan horizon` , again got same error after enable pcntl

i was try to running `composer dump-autoload` , so got new error

[image]

so to solve this error I have added `pcre.jit=0` in **php.ini** file

```
Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
```

from this link : https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7836#issuecomment-447287797

finally restarted apache server from XAMPP , and run `composer dump-autoload`

then last run `php artisan horizon` gives me cleaner output like

> **Horizon started successfully.**

Answer (score 1):

This error is irrelevant to laravel and horizon. 
pcntl_async_signals() is a php method [a link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-async-signals.php) . to enable PCNTL you should compile php with pcntl 
if you use DirectAdmin as control Panel you can use this instructions :
Click [here](https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=252)!